# Implementing your own UserManager, UserStore without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm looking for any insight and/or links for how to implement my own login/registration system for a MVC project. IS it worth using UserManager and UserStore? When you create a new MVC application it relies on Entity framework, thus I'm wondering if it's worth creating my own login/registration process or to use UserManager and UserStore but no longer rely on Entity? Additionally would it perhaps be easier to rely on Entity for that stage of the registration/loging in but create my own table/retrieval methods independent of entity?

To sum up:

1) Should i switch from Entity to use UserManager/UserStore

2) Create my own custom create/manage account controller /models

3) Hybrid it up where I used Entity for logging in / registration and then having my own additional table for additional data just keeping bare data on the entity manage Table.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but why do you want to create a custom login/registration for MVC when its built in?

Comment: @Ryan That's sort of what I'm asking. Can I utilize the login classes "UserManager" and "UserStore" WITHOUT relying on Entity?